# How to change value in html depending on selected option Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have form with select

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option>10 pc</option><!--1 USD -->
  <option>20 pc</option><!--2 USD -->
  <option>50 pc</option><!--3 USD -->
</select>
```

How can I using Javascipt change amount in html h2 depending on selected option?

```
<div class="text-center">
 <h2>Total amount<span style="color:#3972b2">1 USD</span></h2>
</div>
```

When I start form it should be **1 USD** as default for *10pc's* and if I change it to *20pc* it should be **2 USD**

I found such code but it doesn't change

```
$('select[class="form-control"]').on('change',function(){
    var get=$('select option:selected').text();
    $('#new_text').val(get);
});
```

Here is example on http://jsfiddle.net/wc6hrktv/

Thank you!

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/wc6hrktv/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$('#new_text').val(get);
```

to this:

```
$('#new_text').html(get);
```

Comment: it should be $('#new_text').text(get);

Comment: That will work too. In this case, either text or html will work fine, since there's no markup inside of the span.

Comment: I agree both of them will work but since she's not using any markup, it would be better to just use text instead of html

Comment: Why is it better? It's not faster (html is actually about twice as fast as text in this case, since it's just a wrapper around JavaScript's innerHTML, where text has a lot more going on where it needs to check for characters that it would need to encode). I'm not saying you're wrong, I just am curious why you think it's better. I still think either one is fine in this case, since with just one call performance would probably not be a huge consideration; if it was being called in a loop or in a performance critical piece of code, I'd recommend html over text.

Answer (score 0):

set value property of each option in your select tag

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option value="1">10 pc</option><!--1 USD -->
  <option value="2">20 pc</option><!--2 USD -->
  <option value="3">50 pc</option><!--3 USD -->
</select>
```

update value of span by selecting it just like you do in css

```
$('select[class="form-control"]').on('change',function(){
    var get=$('select option:selected').val();

   $('.text-center h2 span').html(get+" USD");
});
```